# style.css not being called in custom created wordpress theme?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Hey everyone I tried the following approaches to no avail.

First

```
<?php 
    wp_head();
    wp_enqueue_style("style.css",get_template_directory_uri());
?>
```

Second

```
<?php
    wp_head();
    wp_enque_style("style.css",get_stylesheet_uri() );
?>
```

Third

```
<?php
    wp_head();
    function my_assets() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'style' , get_template_directory_uri() .'/style.css' );
    }

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_assets' );
    do_action("wp_enque_scripts");
?>
```

Directory Structure

```
hospital_theme[
    style.css
    index.php
    header.php
    footer.php
    sidebar.php
]
```

The theme is custom user created that is it is converted from html file into wordpress theme. Currently theme contains only five files namely header.php, footer.php, sidebar.php, index.php, style.css.

I have used get_header(), get_footer() to successfully call the contents of respective files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We create a new file called `functions.php` in theme directory. 
Please enter following code in `functions.php`

```
function wpdocs_theme_name_scripts() {
   wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', get_stylesheet_uri().'/style.css' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpdocs_theme_name_scripts' );
```

Answer (score 1):

There is one more way to add the CSS. You can add following code in header.php file.

```
<link href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this below code. They're normally loaded using this code in header.php file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" />
```

Hope it will works for you.

Answer (score -2):

In WP Admin: Appearance > Editor > Header.php and put simple html
`<link src=""...>`
[My print Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Go5pK.png)

Comment: It's <link rel="stylesheet" href="path to css file">